# SP2013 - Tasks updating automatically. Can't figure out why

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks

So we have a homegrown IT request system built off of out-of-the-box lists and SPD workflows. The idea is that a user submits an IT request (request list), a workflow (on the request lists) gets kicked off and creates an item (of content type IT Request Task) in a task list. The task is created in an impersonation step using a system account. If the request has any kind of formatting in its description field, it will copy over to the newly created task with no issue. After a few minutes though, the task automatically update itself and remove all the formatting on the description on the task. There are no workflows on the task that get kicked off on creation, but there is one on edit which will pass information back to the original request if something changes.

I have confirmed that it is not an issue with the request list at all. I manually created a new task (of content type IT Request Task) with some formatted description field text. After a few minutes, the task had updated itself and lost its formatting on the description field.

Has anyone encountered this at all or know of any reason why this would be happening?

Comment: I think it has to do with a timer job, but I can't pinpoint which one.

Comment: Also, weird. It's not happening on our development server. Only production.

Comment: were you able to figure out the issue?

Comment: @TaranGoel It's been so long, but I think the issue was that we had enabled some sort of task syncing between SharePoint and Outlook. Once we turned that off, it stopped happening. I think it was a feature we disabled.

Comment: it would be really really helpful if you can provide more details..I am stuck in this critical issue for very long:(

Comment: @TaranGoel Well the problem stopped when we disabled Task Synchronization between Exchange and SharePoint. I believe the sync ends up modifying some back-end fields that users can't see on the task itself, which ended up changing all our rich-text to plain text (on that one task list). Not sure I can be much more help than that.

Comment: Just last bit of info please. How did you stop the sync? Sorry for being this annoying!

Comment: @TaranGoel I wasn't the person who set it up, but I think might help: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38799